# HDMI Audio on an Acer Aspire Revo (Nividia ION) is only stereo

Tags: audio, hdmi, nvidia-ion

I have an acer aspire revo connected via HDMI to a 5.1 surround sound system. It uses the nvidia ION graphics chipset.

I can only get it into 2 channel stereo mode, as far as i can tell its supposed to be capable of 8 channel sound.

It has 64bit windows 7, and ive updated the HDMI Audio drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7.1 surround is supported by HDMI but not by ION, every ION mainboard and computer I've found are 6 channel. Make sure your speakers are set to 5.1 under the sound panel in control panel. Also make sure 5.1 speakers are set in the sound card properties, usually realtek.

Comment: The Realtek sound manager is for the optical out on the front of the revo

Comment: Ive swapped to using the optical out and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

5.1 sound works fine on my Revo with Windows 7 (x86).

and no, 7.1 (to the best of my knowledge) is NOT supported.

Comment: No idea. I can find any indication of anomolies on the voting, but they could be using sockpuppets. Will take some time later this evening to investigate globally.